# How to debug Django/WSGI/Apache errors

Tags: django, mod-wsgi

I have a Django 1.11.17 application deployed on Apache 2 and WSGI, Python 2.7.

Apache shows an error "Truncated or oversized response headers received from daemon process"

I have checked the solution given in 
[WSGI : Truncated or oversized response headers received from daemon process](https://serverfault.com/questions/844761/wsgi-truncated-or-oversized-response-headers-received-from-daemon-process)

and `WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}` is in the virtual host file. However the error persists.

Django shell works. Django check returns no errors. Django runserver works. Django log shows no errors.

How can I see the exact error that is making WSGI not working?

Comment: Can you switch to nginx?

Comment: Yes, I could switch to nginx, but I would like to know how to fix it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a debugging mode that you can use provided by `mod_wsgi`. You can find the documentation here:
https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/debugging-techniques.html

However, we found that we were using third-party packages such as `numpy` or `psycopg2-binary` that were causing issues. In our case, we were using psycopg2-binary which is a big no no for production apps. We removed it and followed their documentation on pip installation and everything worked. We also added `WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}` to our apache2 server settings.

You may find the `psycopg` documentation at http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#prerequisites

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you fo the answer Paul, how did you find that those third-party packages where causing issues?

Comment: Since the project worked outside of the daemon process, I knew it had to do with an installation or configuration issue. After a couple of days tweaking my configuration files with no luck, I spent a week reading through the documentation of all the packages in my requirements.txt and a shiz ton of googling. I found statements about how you should install packages from the source code, because they can cause conflicts with system libraries. With the process of elimination, we identified the packages and reinstalled.

Comment: from the above `psycopg` documentation i can see that v2.7 is having issues, but i am using 
`psycopg2==2.8.4`
`psycopg2-binary==2.8.5`.
and getting same error! :(

Comment: @SusajSN Have you checked out the debugging tool that mod_wsgi provides? It can give you some more context to your error. It also might not be psycopg2 that is causing the issue. It might be your python tools installed on your server, another pip package, or a settings problem in your apache virtual host file.