# Timeout when reading response headers from daemon process 'horizon': /opt/stack/horizon/openstack_dashboard/wsgi.py

Tags: wsgi

When trying to allocate a floating IP in openstack (on Ubuntu 18.04.1), I'm getting this error. "Danger: There was an error submitting the form. Please try again"

In /var/log/apache2/horizon_error.log, I can see the following message. 2019-01-30 15:57:55.500972 Timeout when reading response headers from daemon process 'horizon': /opt/stack/horizon/openstack_dashboard/wsgi.py

It seems to be the same issue as in the question below.

[initial question](https://serverfault.com/questions/514242/non-responsive-apache-mod-wsgi-after-installing-scipy/951668#951668)

Workaround seems to be to add WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
which I have already in /etc/apache2/sites-available/horizon.conf

I don't know what else shoudl I modify.

WSGIScriptAlias /dashboard /opt/stack/horizon/openstack_dashboard/wsgi.py WSGIDaemonProcess horizon user=stack group=stack processes=3 threads=10 home=/opt/stack/horizon display-name=%{GROUP}
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

SetEnv APACHE_RUN_USER stack
SetEnv APACHE_RUN_GROUP stack
WSGIProcessGroup horizon

DocumentRoot /opt/stack/horizon/.blackhole/
Alias /dashboard/media /opt/stack/horizon/openstack_dashboard/static
Alias /dashboard/static /opt/stack/horizon/static

RedirectMatch "^/$" "/dashboard/"

Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    # Apache 2.4 uses mod_authz_host for access control now (instead of
    #  "Allow")
    
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    
    = 2.4>
        Require all granted
    

= 2.4>
  ErrorLogFormat "%{cu}t %M"

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/horizon_error.log
LogLevel warn
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/horizon_access.log combined